# How to reduce the side effects of wearing contact lens?

Tags: side-effects, eye, ophthalmology, optometry, contact-lenses

[This](http://www.insightvisioncenter.com/dark-side-wearing-contact-lenses/) explains a lot of side effect of wearing contact lens. The type of contact lens Iam talking about is silicon hydrogel lenses.

Questions:

1) Till how many hours can lens be worn continuously?

2) How many minutes of break should be given to the eyes?

3) Will washing the eyes with water or inducing crying will help to reduce corneal scarring, etc as it helps in lubrication.

4) Can looking at the computer while wearing the lens have any potential side effects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Questions 1-2

Unfortunately, the answer to these depend on the exact brand and line of contacts used. For example, [here](https://www.alensa.co.uk/dictionary/oxygen-permeability.html) is a long list of silicon hydrogel lenses, and how long they last. [Here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_soft_contact_lens_materials) is another list of materials used to make contact lenses (including many of the silicon hydrogel type). Some of those are dailies, but some can be worn day and night , such as the [extended wear](https://www.alensa.co.uk/dictionary/extended-wear.html) contacts listed here. You can usually look up your particular contact lenses online and find the maximum recommended time.  However, I'd recommend (as would most eye doctors) that you generally wear them less than the maximum, just to be safe. For example, I use Biofinity lenses, which are approved to be worn for up to 7 days, but I usually wear them for no more than 2-3 days at a time.

The concerns here are how much oxygen gets to the eye, and how much material builds up on the contact lens. Some brands of contacts have much higher oxygen permeability, so you can wear them longer without damaging your eye.

Protein buildup is one factor in how uncomfortable contacts get, and it [also depends](http://www.contactlenses.org/rgpvsoft.htm) on the material of the contact lens.

Similarly bacteria (and other microorganisms) buildup on your eye and contact lens depends on the material - and that will affect how long the contacts last and how long each day (or week) you can wear them.

### Question 3

No idea about the tears, but you [shouldn't allow water to touch contacts](https://www.cdc.gov/contactlenses/water-and-contact-lenses.html). (Thanks Narusan for the comment).

### Question 4

Not aside from the same side effects that would be present for someone without contact lenses looking at a computer. Wearing contact lenses to fix vision is much closer to the natural optical system than glasses - so from and optical perspective, wearing contact lenses is almost exactly the same as having eyes that don't need correction at all. This is not true of glasses, which cause your muscles to move and your eyes to focus in different ways than they would if you didn't need glasses.

Comment: I can help with Q3: Under no circumstances should one combine water and contact lenses. [It's not good for the contact lenses, and it hurts your eyes as well](https://www.cdc.gov/contactlenses/water-and-contact-lenses.html). Also speaking from experience...

Comment: @Narusan What about induced crying? Not by any chemical agents, just emotionally.

Comment: @user29535 I'm jealous if you can cry so much that it will be sufficient lubrication. There are special lotions (for a reason) and I would simply use them. As there are different kinds, you might have to try around, some burn in the eye, others don't.